# Run detatched script on linux after .net parent exits?

Tags: .net, linux, shell, detach

I have want my .Net Linux service to start a bash shell script, which stops its parent service, while the script continues.

This can be done on straight Linux easily, with nohup and &.

It can be done in Windows .net, by writing a stub .exe or script which starts the persisting script, then stops its parent. In that case, the stub and the parent die, but the script the sub started continues.

However, in .net on Linux, this does not seem to work. My .net app can issue a shell command with nohup, but the sub-script - which is also started with nohup and &, and which is the one which is supposed the actual work, does not run.

The stub `update1.sh`, is run from the .net app with

```
nohup /usr/bin/myservice/update1.sh update.rpm &
```

It contains:

```
trap '' SIGTERM
trap '' SIGINT
nohup /usr/bin/myservice/update2.sh $1 &
```

`update2.sh` contains

```
trap '' SIGTERM
trap '' SIGINT
sudo systemctl stop myservice
yum -y localinstall $1
sudo systemctl start myservice
```

(the traps are intended to prevent the parent's shutting down from 
stopping the child)

If I start update1.sh from the command line, while su'd to the service user account, with nohup and &, it works fine. The problem arises when I start up the stub from inside the .net app, with the same command line. It appears to be related to running in the .net managed code environment.

Any suggestions?

The goal is to take an .net app running on an unattended Centos server, and allow it to update and restart itself using 'yum -y localinstall' and a local RPM file (no, it can't go to a remote repository).

Comment: Does it log any errors? If not, please double check that you'd be able to see any errors by adding `echo "test message" >&2` to the script and ensuring that you can see it in the error log. If you can't see any, please set up error logging. It's likely that `sudo` is failing when run non-interactively.

Comment: I redirect output to a log file (not shown). To repeat, the script runs just fine if I, logged in as the service user,  issue `nohup /usr/bin/myservice/update1.sh update.rpm &`. I've also been able to run scripts this way which do NOT stop the service, just restart it. The user has the appropriate sudoers.d entries to run sudo systemctl without a password.

Comment: There are several potential differences between running from bash on a tty and running via some framework's external command. For example, `nohup` is unlikely to redirect output and errors when invoked via .NET, which can cause disappearing logs and write failures. What does the log currently show? Have you verified that your logging mechanism would capture from all relevant lines when run via .NET, given how it will no longer end up in `nohup.out` like it would when you ran it manually?

Comment: Yes, I have. An earlier version of this did not shut down the parent, but installed each version into versioned directory (/usr/bin/myservice-1.2.3.4). When installation was complete, a symlink (usr/bin/myservice) was moved to point to it, and the service restarted. That worked fine, and the logs contained everything I expected. but tended to leave empty, old versioned directories in /usr/bin. I was asked to try to find a way to stop the service, install into the /usr/bin/myservice directory, and then restart it, all kicked off from the old version of myservice when it received a new RPM file.